# Копировать диапазон строк в файл. vim

Tags: vim

Требуется скопировать из одного файла в другой диапазон строк

```
:r ~/path/to/file - копировать весь файл
```

Как скопировать диапазон строк?

```
1-10;
2,4,6,8,10.
```

Answer (score 1):

в командном режиме
`:10,20 w ~/path/to/file`
диапазон с 10 по 20 строки скопирует в файл `~/path/to/file`

Answer (score 0):

Может быть, имеет смысл эти строки скопировать традиционным способом?

Перейти в режим визуального выделения строк - клавиша V, выделить первый диапазон и скопировать его, например, в буфер *a* - сочетание клавиш *"ay*.

Затем выделить второй диапазон и **добавить** его в буфер - кливишами *"Ay*.

Ну и в файле назначения просто вставить накопленные в буфере строки - *"ap*.